# Link Matlab to Window Application

Tags: matlab, winapi, message-queue

How compatible are Matlab and .EXE files? Is it possible to make win32 APIs send messages to matlab and for matlab to read them in real time?

More precisely can I make Matlab to receive and handle messages from another application at real time?

When I am handling such messages, I also have a concern with the type of loop I would have to use in Matlab. Is an infinite for/while loop a good practice?

for example

```
while(infinite loop)
if (received message)
    do something
end
end
```

Note, above is algorithm only, not intended as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question: the [Matlab Engine](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-matlab-engine.html) seems to be what you are after.

The second part of your question: in many coding standards, it's often recommended to avoid infinite loops. The problem with infinite loops is, well, that they may never end :) It's all too easy to incorrectly or incompletely code the exit condition(s), causing your loop to never end and the program's execution to stall. This sort of bug can pop up in unit testing (often-failing exit condition), or only after the first batch of your customers start complaining about your program crashing (not-so-often failing exit condition). These (and many other) pitfalls of infinite loops are often avoidable by

- translating the infinite loop to a finite one
- setting a maximum on the amount of iterations
- using a whole different paradigm altogether.

With [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), where part of the program is listening to messages from other parts of the program or other programs alltogether, the last option is best. Using an [event based approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) prevents an infinite loop. MATLAB supports this in the form of [events and listeners](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners--concepts.html). This is part of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) in MATLAB, so you'd have to have followed OOP already, or convert everything you have to OOP in order to use it.

Comment: Infinite loops are fine if you get the exit condition right. What is the difference between a `while true` loop with a conditional break, and a `while condition`? There is no difference. Your second paragraph is way off base. Message loops are never written as finite loops with maximum iterations. Imagine the fun when you program terminate because it had received the maximum number of messages that you coded. I suggest you delete that entire part of the answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I was contending that while `while condition` is the same as `while true` in principle, in practice people tend to implement it more robustly. I've seen bugs of this sort one too many times. I am also not saying that it is an absolute rule, always to be followed. I *am* saying that it is *advised by many* to avoid them, but not at all cost. I *am* saying that it is *very easy* to write a resource hog in the form of an infinite loop that handles messages (especially in something like MATLAB), while the event-driven paradigm (usually) prevents this sort of thing.

Comment: How do you think event driven paradigm is implement? I sense a `while` loop. Do you think that `while` loop will be finite, or have a maximum number of iterations?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thanks for your answer. For the first paragraph, it's kind of other way around (or rather mixed). I also want to use Windows Application and Matlab GUI. Receive data from Window Application and Plot in Matlab. I am aware of Message Loops in WinAPIs. It was stupid (possibly) of me to think that messages might be handled differently and not via message loop by MatLab (if possible).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Probably, yes. Look, there sure are situations where manipulating strings defined by character arrays, with `strcpy` and friends, never forgetting the trailing `\0`, etc. are the better way to go. But *generally* you'd advise people to use `std::string` and only resort to low-level stuff when needed, right? Behind the scenes, both will do the exact same thing, but out in the wild, one is just less prone to error than the other. This is why it's *guideline*, not *law*, *advised*, not *obliged*.

Comment: Is it a good guideline to suggest writing a message loop with a finite number of iterations?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: no; but switching to the event-driven paradigm is :)

Comment: So if you know that's not good advice, why does your answer still contain it. Please do feel free to improve the answer.